# adb REMOTE pull file to desktop

Tags: android, adb

Android: adb pull file on desktop
Trying to copy file from remote device to desktop, here is a command:

adb -s xx.xx.xx.xx:5555 pull sdcard/screen.png c:/users/xx/desktop/

But I always get the message:

cannot create 'c:\users\xx\desktop\': No such file or directory!! | in sdcard

if i run the same command whitout dir path 
adb pull <**remote**> [local]
adb -s xx.xx.xx.xx:5555 pull sdcard/log.txt log1.txt

it well copy file screen.png to the same android sdcard dir not sdk folder in my windows Os

do adb has the ability to transfer file over tcp/ip like the documentation (adb pull <**remote**> [local]) or  im wrong ??

Comment: The error message is already telling you: there's no such directory `c:\users\xx\desktop`.

Comment: No sir ! the errore is teling that is no sucg dir c:\..... in sdcard

Comment: @alex-p p this Q is not duplicated at all read the Q befor flag it

Comment: @DavidP.Swanson check the second answer in the linked question (the one from Alex), you should understand why this question is a duplicate of that.

Comment: @DavidP.Swanson I've been pulling and pushing files for 6 years now. Please teach me how it works.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes i can teach you and with pleasure mr 6year
the answer is removing the last "/"
adb -s xx.xx.xx.xx:5555 pull sdcard/screen.png c:/users/xx/desktop/ << this

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, "/" is for defining path in Unix systems. Try to use "\" as Windows systems define path.

Comment: i have alrady didit the result is no such as dir : c:usersxxdesktop

Comment: Try removing the last "/" or "\". Leave the path open